# IE misses Headers - angular $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I`m trying to fetch results from remote server (inaturalist.org) using angularjs $http. The server use headers to specify Paging information (total entries, page, etc).

My problem is when using IE (Edge, IE11 tested) I cant see all the headers.

```
$http({
method  : 'GET',
url     : 'https://www.inaturalist.org/observations.json?page=1&per_page=30'})
.success(function (data, status, headers) {

   scope.headers = headers();
});
```

});

See https://jsbin.com/rohoda/edit?js,output

Any idea whats wrong ?

Comment: Wow, this looks like a bug in Internet Explorer's `XMLHttpRequest` implementation for CORS requests. The server correctly returns the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Per-Page, X-Total-Entries` response header but apparently the `X-Total-Entries` header cannot be obtained with the [`getResponseHeader`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20121206/#the-getresponseheader()-method) method (which is what this `headers` function represents in Angular's `$http` implementation).

Comment: Yep, Ive tested this with jQuery as well, same results

Comment: Yes, both jQuery and Angular resort to the native `XMLHttpRequest` object. Very nice catch. But maybe IE simply doesn't support the `Access-Control-Expose-Header` CORS response header.

Comment: Checkout this article: http://leopard.in.ua/2012/07/08/using-cors-with-rails/ There's a paragraph right at the bottom called `Access-Control-Expose-Headers problem`. It seems that only Google Chrome correctly implements the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Internet Explorer's implementation of the XMLHttpRequest object. Since you are making a cross domain request CORS rules apply. It is a GET request so it is not necessary to make a pre-flight OPTIONS request. The server correctly returns the following response header:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Per-Page, X-Total-Entries
```

and yet you cannot access the `X-Total-Entries` response header using the [`getResponseHeader()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20121206/#the-getresponseheader()-method) method (which is what this `header` variable represents in the success callback).

The only browser that fully and correctly implements this `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` CORS header is Google Chrome.

You may find the [`following article`](http://leopard.in.ua/2012/07/08/using-cors-with-rails/) useful and especially the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers problem` section right at the bottom:

> All browsers (except Google Chrome) have buggy getRequestHeader()
>   implementations, so the headers may not be accessible to clients even
>   after you set the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header. In my example,
>   ETag header accessible only in Google Chrome browser. Safari return
>   only simple response headers, while Firefox doesn't return ANY
>   response headers.

I am afraid that the only workaround here is to setup a proxy script on your domain that will act as a bridge between your domain and the remote domain. Then make the AJAX request to your own domain to avoid the need of using CORS.